# Hssf Bold property not working in partial file in excel 2007-10

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

Am using poi3.7 to create xlsx, its looking fine with openoffice but bold font not support in entire ms excel 2007 and 2010. its partially looking bold

```
style = objWorkbook.createCellStyle();
font = objWorkbook.createFont();
font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
style.setFont(font);
objHSSFCell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(value));
objHSSFCell.setCellStyle(style);
```

pls give your suggestion to resolve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems you are using HSSF instead of XSSF for xlsx. Hence, though `HSSFRichTextString` is valid for an `HSSFCell`, you need `XSSFCell` instead and then set its value with `XSSFRichTextString`.

Comment: your're welcome. I have upgraded my comment to an answer so you can accept it for closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading comment to an answer;

Seems you are using `HSSF` instead of `XSSF` for xlsx. Hence, though [`HSSFRichTextString`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html) is valid for an `HSSFCell`, you need `XSSFCell` instead and then set its value with [`XSSFRichTextString`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html).